# Add a referential constraint with a constant value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table of locations:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[loca_location] (
    [loca_id] [int] NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    [loca_name] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [loca_address_line_1] [nvarchar](100),
    [loca_address_line_2] [nvarchar](100),
    [loca_address_line_3] [nvarchar](100),
    [loca_address_town] [nvarchar](100),
    [loca_address_county] [nvarchar](100),
    [loca_post_code] [nvarchar](12),
    [loca_active] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [loca_created] [datetimeoffset](0) NOT NULL,
    [loca_created_by] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [loca_modified] [datetimeoffset](0) NOT NULL,
    [loca_modified_by] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [loca_deleted] [datetimeoffset](0),
    [loca_deleted_by] [nvarchar](50),
    [loca_type] [char](1),
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.loca_store] PRIMARY KEY ([loca_id])
)
```

Now some locations may be my own, others may be customers. If customer, then `loca_type` will be `C`. If I own it, it will be `L`. If its a supplier, then it will be `S`.

Now a contract should always belong to a customer, so I want to make it so the `loca_type` = `C` is a constraint as well as the `loca_id`.

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[cont_contract] ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.cont_contract_dbo.loca_location_cust_id] FOREIGN KEY ([loca_id_customer]) REFERENCES [dbo].[loca_location] ([loca_id], `C`)
```

That doesn't work. Is it possible to do what I want?

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do... are you asking if it's possible to have a column be an `int`-based ID value while also being a constant `C` `char` value...?  If that's your question, then no.

Comment: @Tim, You cannot do that with a single column. Like Siyual said, you can only check against one data type. When you have a foreign key constraint, any value which violates the condition will fail the insert/update query.

Comment: Agree with Siyual, there is probably a way to do what you want, but your question is totally unclear to me.

Comment: Serg's solution would work however such a _central dictionary_ might have other problems because of hundreds and thouthands of incoming FKs. They would make it impossible to delete a single row from this table for example. Also any alterations on this table would face performance and locking troubles. Another thing is that I can't get the idea of your model: `location` **IS** `customer`? `location` IS `other entity`? Usually customers have several addresses and customer entity is not dependent on address. Addresses are usually linked to a customer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may work

1.Declare UNIQUE ([loca_id],  [loca_type] ) on [loca_location] table. That is correct as any superset of PK is unique.

2.Add constant column to [cont_contract] table.

3.Create FK.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[loca_location] (
    [loca_id] [int] NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    --..
    [loca_type] [char](1) CHECK ([loca_type] IN ('A','B','C')),  -- change as needed
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.loca_store] PRIMARY KEY ([loca_id])
)
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[loca_location] ADD CONSTRAINT [u1] UNIQUE ([loca_id],[loca_type]);


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[cont_contract] (
    [id] [int] NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    --..
    [loca_id_customer] Int,
    -- Constant column
    [loca_type] [char](1) DEFAULT 'C' CHECK ([loca_type] ='C')
);

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[cont_contract] ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.cont_contract_dbo.loca_location_cust_id] 
                    FOREIGN KEY ([loca_id_customer],[loca_type]) REFERENCES [dbo].[loca_location] ([loca_id], [loca_type]);
```

Comment: Yeah I see how that its a round-a-bout way of doing it, thanks! Shame cannot be done without the column in contracts.